# How to remove blank space between streambuilder and CustomCarouselSlider

Tags: flutter, dart

please help, I have a streambuilder and  CustomCarouselSlider but there's a white space displaying between them that i can't get rid of.[image]  I have atttached an image to show how both of them are displaying.The white space is just a bummer, Both are fetching data from firestore here is the code:

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                      children: [
                        StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
                          stream: _tipsStreamController.stream,
                          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                              return CarouselSlider.builder(
                                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int realIndex) {
                                  DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data![index];
                                  return TransparentImageCard(
                                    width: 400,
                                    imageProvider: NetworkImage(doc['imageUrl']),
                                    tags: [
                                      _tag(doc['tag1'], () {}),
                                      _tag(doc['tag2'], () {}),
                                    ],
                                    title: _title(text: doc['title'], color: Colors.white),
                                    description: _content(text: doc['description'], color: Colors.white),
                                    footer: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.add_chart_sharp)),
                                  );
                                },
                                options: CarouselOptions(
                                  height: 400,
                                  autoPlay: true,
                                  enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                  viewportFraction: 0.99,
                                  autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
                                ),
                              );
                            } else {
                              return  CircularProgressIndicator();
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                        
                        CustomCarouselSlider(
                            items: itemList,
                            height:400,
                            subHeight: 80,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.99,
                            autoplay: true,
                            autoplayDuration:Duration(seconds: 20)
    
    
                        ),
    
                      ],
                    ),
          ),
```

[image: i want to remove the blank white space in the middle]

Comment: remove height & use aspectRatio parameter

Comment: CarouselOptions.height=400, when your picture does not have a height of 400, it will be blank. You should not limit the height of the CarouselSlider, you can try to display it according to the aspect ratio